# Why is my ip in ipconfig and the one shown in whatismyip.com different?

Tags: ip-address

Which is my real IP? The one shown in ipconfig /all or the one shown in ([whatismyip.org](http://www.whatismyip.org/)) (I'll just call it WISMIP for short)?

If I'm not wrong, the one in WISMIP is the IP from my ISP's proxy?

Does this mean that if a site blocks this IP, its blocking everyone who routes through this proxy?

Finally, when I look at ipconfig /all, I should be looking under IPv4 address?

My IP has been blocked by my hosting service, which IP should I provide so they could remove me from the block list?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[whatismyip.org](http://whatismyip.org/) will show you the address that your ISP has provided to you: this is the IP address that everyone else in the world can see, and the one that is blocked. Unless you are connecting directly to your ISP - no router, no wireless - this would not be what shows up in ipconfig. This is very unusual, that a (non-server) computer is directly connected to the internet as a whole.

If there is any box at all in between your computer and your ISP, your computer will probably have a different IP. The reason is that there is a finite number of IPs in the world, so there has to be some way of conserving them. That way is [NAT, or Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT).

Essentially your router hands out IPs to every machine in your space - office, house, whatever - and handles all traffic behind itself. It passes all that traffic along the one link with the one global IP address provided by your ISP. So every computer's traffic appears to come from that one IP address. For incoming traffic, it catches the return packets, and routes them to the correct internal address. In this way, you can reuse more or less the whole address space of IP in your intranet without colliding with a valuable global address.

If you look at your router's configuration page, you should be able to find a page with the allocation for each computer - it'll probably be labled [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhcp). Alternatively, you can go to [whatismyip.org](http://www.whatismyip.org/) from two different computers that connect to the same router, and you should see the same ip for both.

Comment: I am little confused with the line "For incoming traffic". If incoming packets are coming for a IP address that router have, then how that router identify and redirect packets to the correct internal device.

Comment: @Abhisheksaharn when you send(output) some data/request etc from your computer1 to the internet, computer1 adds its LAN IP to a header and appends that header to the data packet. Then this packet arrives to the router, router then also appends WAN IP address of it on top of the packet and sends the packet to the outer internet. That way, when the response arrives to the router from the outer world, it contains the IP address where the request was sent. Not being sure, that is probably how it works.

Answer (score 4):

If a site is blocking an ip, it's only blocking your external ip, ip config shows your internal ip. Changing your internal ip makes no change to if a site blocks you. If your ip is dynamically assigned by your ISP rebooting your router might sometimes give you a new external ip. Otherwise your ip will be fixed so once your blocked the only way to access a site then is either through a VPN, proxy or by getting the ISP to give you another ip or getting a new ISP.
And yes you should be looking at the ipv4, well in the Uk anyway as I don't know of any ISPs that use 6 yet although I know it's in testing.

Answer (score 0):

You're connect to a router, no? Your ipconfig will show your local ip. The websites will show your routers IP with your ISP. Give them the one Whatismyip says. That is the one all websites will see.

Comment: Hi thanks, will do that. Nope, I'm connected straight to my cable modem.